# How can I add some string to a list in order to make a count word? [Python]

Tags: python, windows, list

I want to simply add some word to a list and then count how many words are in there...

And check if the word isn't in the list already.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list can be used for this, but if speed is important and order doesn't matter then a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) will be faster.

```
>>> S = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> S
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> 'b' in S
True
>>> S.add('d')
>>> S
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
>>> S.add('b')
>>> S
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

Comment: make an example please, speed is impostqant and order doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

You can add a word to a list by calling `alist.append("word")` where alist is your list.

To count how many words are in the list simply use `len(alist)`.

To check if the word isn't already in the list use `if "word" not in alist:`

-edit to remove references to word 'list', replacing it with 'alist'

Comment: The obvious python primitive to use in this case is a set, not a list